# Restore a SQL Server database to an offline copy

Tags: sql-server, restore, ssms

I have SQL Server Management Studio. I need to access a backup file (`*.bak`).

How do I create a new database engine that is OFFLINE (running from my PC not the server) and then restore the database to that offline database engine?

Comment: Why you want the server to be offline? It can not be offline - it has to process the restore. You mix something up seriously here. It makes no sense for the database engine not to be online.

Answer (score 4):

1. Install SQL Server, if it isn't already there.
2. Get the backup file onto you local box.
3. Open SSMS and connect to your local instance
4. Right-click the "Databases" folder and pick "Restore Database..."
5. Follow the wizard until you're done

Comment: How do I check if SQL server is installed I've got: "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2" under my programs where I've found SSMS.  Sorry for the stupid questions.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how could you not know whether or not SQL Server is installed and yet you want to restore a database?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to do an instance install on your PC.  Then with that stand-alone instance you will be able to restore your database in the fashion you want on your isolated environment.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  I have the Management studio software on my pc.

Comment: Having SSMS on your PC isn't enough.  You need to actually have a SQL Server instance on your machine to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want?

To see if you have a local server installed open up an app called
"sql server configuration manager"

Under SQL Server Services you should be able to see if anything is running or not.

To Connect to your local instance. (SQL Server Management Studio)

1. Click on file
2. Connect object explorer
3. Under servername type "localhost"

In Object explorer

[image]

1. Right click on the Databases folder underneath the server you want to restore to (your local server in this instance)
2. New Database, then follow the prompts. (this is the db you'll restore your backup to)
3. [a] Restore database (select the newly create database,

   [b] and choose from device and select the backup file.

   [c] Under options, choose to overwrite the db) an run the restore

Comment: Yes almost, except I want an offline database engine

Comment: Why offline if i might ask? If its a local instance. Restore then take it offline?

Comment: I need to compare data between yesterday & today and I don't want to add it on the server, afraid I'll mess something up, so that's why I need it offline.  What do you mean by local instance?

Comment: To be honest, I've never heard of restoring to an offline instance... by logic it needs to be active for you to interact with it. But what do I know :/

Comment: Local instance => Running from my PC not the server. You needs something like sql server express or some dev version of full blow sql on your dev machine. Connect to it, Then follow the instructions I gave you

Comment: I found SQL Server Configuration Manager on my machine, this means SQL server is installed right? so whereto from here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13463/discussion-between-rohan-buchner-and-wilest)

Comment: No it doesn't mean you have a running server instance on your machine. I've created a chat if you need help.